# Prevent events from overlapping while dragging

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have an Issue, if you have already an event and drag another over this, the events will be drawn on top of each other. After drop the Event it will appear a line under the first. Now you can switch it in this lane. But initially it looks not good.

[image: Excample]

Comment: It's not possible with a simple CSS change. The dragging event is `.fc-timeline-event-harness`, but as is has `position: absolute` it isn't aware of what is underneath. It is possible you could hook into the JavaScript and perform a calculation to check for events, but it wouldn't be straightforward. See: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing

Comment: If you think there is a bug in fullCalendar, or you want to make a suggestion for a feature, you can do so [via the instructions here](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) (bugs) [or here](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) (features). On stackoverflow we can help you with issues with your implementation of fullCalendar on your website, and with interacting with its API etc, but we can't support you around issues in the core code.